# Insert Data from CSV to HTML table using powershell

Tags: html, powershell, csv

I am new to powershell and I want to insert the data from csv to html table which is I create separately. This is my csv

```
Sitename     EmailAddress
Test         example@gmail.com
```

Asking for help of how should I insert this data to my html table and then if I add data in csv it also automatically added on HTML table.

test.ps1 script

```
$kfxteam = Get-Content ('.\template\teamnotif.html') 
$notifteam = '' #result html
$teamlist = Import-Csv ".\list\teamlist.csv" | select 'SiteName','EmailAddress'
For($a=0; $a -lt $kfxteam.Length; $a++) {
# If the "<table class=content>" matches on what written on $kfxteam it will show the result`
if($kfxteam -match "<table class=content >"){ 
    # should be replacing the data came from csv to html and also adding new row
write-host $teamlist[$a].SiteName      
}
}
```

html format

```
<<table class=content >
            <td class=c1 nowrap>
                Remote Sitenames
                </td>
                <td class=c1 nowrap >
                Users Email Address
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=c1 nowrap>
                usitename
                </td>
                <td class=c1 nowrap>
                [uemail]
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

The output html table should be

Remote Sitenames   Email Address
Test               example@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd change the HTML template file regarding the table to become something like this:

```
<table class=content>
<tr>
  <td class=c1 nowrap>Remote Sitenames</td>
  <td class=c1 nowrap>Users Email Address</td>
</tr>
@@TABLEROWSHERE@@
</table>
```

Now, you have a placeholder which you can replace with the table rows you create using the CSV file like:

```
# create a template for each of the rows to insert 
# with two placeholders to fill in using the -f Format operator
$row = @"
<tr>
  <td class=c1 nowrap>{0}</td>
  <td class=c1 nowrap>{1}</td>
</tr>
"@

# import the csv, loop over the records and use the $row template to create the table rows
$tableRows = Import-Csv -Path '.\list\teamlist.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $row -f $_.Sitename, $_.EmailAddress
}

# then combine it all in the html
$result = (Get-Content -Path '.\template\teamnotif.html' -Raw) -replace '@@TABLEROWSHERE@@', ($tableRows -join [Environment]::NewLine)

# save the completed HTML
$result | Set-Content -Path '.\list\teamlist.html'
```

Comment: this work for me so if I added data to csv it automatically added also on html?

Comment: @siennac Yes, all data from the csv will be inserted into the html. BTW. Being new to the platform you may not know this, but it is customary to mark the question 'done' by clicking the large checkmark icon on the left of the answer. This also helps others with a similar question finding it more easily.